# JBoss Seam project can not be run/deployed

Tags: jboss

I created sample application in Seam framework (Seam Web Project) and JBoss Server 7.1. When I try run application, console dislays:

```
23:29:35,419 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."secoundProject-ds.xml".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."secoundProject-ds.xml".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "secoundProject-ds.xml"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: local-tx-datasource
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ParserException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: local-tx-datasource
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parseDataSources(DsParser.java:183)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:119)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:80)
    ... 6 more

23:29:35,452 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment secoundProject-ds.xml in 1ms
23:29:35,455 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015863: Replacement of deployment "secoundProject-ds.xml" by deployment "secoundProject-ds.xml" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"secoundProject-ds.xml\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"secoundProject-ds.xml\".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"secoundProject-ds.xml\""}}
23:29:35,457 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "secoundProject-ds.xml"
23:29:35,920 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."secoundProject-ds.xml".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."secoundProject-ds.xml".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "secoundProject-ds.xml"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: local-tx-datasource
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ParserException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: local-tx-datasource
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parseDataSources(DsParser.java:183)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:119)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:80)
    ... 6 more

23:29:35,952 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."secoundProject-ds.xml".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."secoundProject-ds.xml".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "secoundProject-ds.xml"
```

My secoundProject-ds.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE datasources
    PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS JCA Config 1.5//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-ds_1_5.dtd">
<datasources>

   <local-tx-datasource>
      <jndi-name>secoundProjectDatasource</jndi-name>
      <use-java-context>true</use-java-context>
      <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database</connection-url>
      <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
      <user-name>root</user-name>
      <password></password>
   </local-tx-datasource>

</datasources>
```

When I comment  tags errors disappear, but application is disabled in browser (`The requested resource (/secoundProject/) is not available.`). 
What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your *-ds.xml file is not configured correctly.  Try this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
   <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/secoundProjectDatasource" use-java-context="true">
      <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database</connection-url>
      <driver>mysql</driver>
      <security>
         <user-name>root</user-name>
         <password>somePassword</password>
      </security>
   </datasource>
</datasources>
```